# Including line-break when displaying date within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to display the date to a DIV formatted with the day centered above the month (DD 
 MMMM). However, the page only displays the day. When I inspect element the line break and month are being sent properly.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {    

    var value = moment().subtract(2,'days');

$(".slider").each(function() {
    var dateFormatted = moment(value).format("DD" + "<br/>" + "MMMM");

    $(this).html(dateFormatted);
    value = value.add(1,'days');
});}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="carousel-items">
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

I could also use a suggestion for another technique to accomplish the same thing. But I do need an each loop in the JQuery because the dates will be generated continuously.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a styling issue, can you post your CSS as well?

Comment: [Works fine without any styling](http://jsfiddle.net/p963kkp1/), I suspect your "slider" divs are styled very narrow

Comment: What's the problem? Is the month not displayed or is nothing displayed? I understood that everything works, the month is "THERE", but you can't see it, right? Can you edit a JSFiddle to that problem, so we can see the problem too? If I understood it the rigth way, maybe `.slider` needs a height.

Comment: What is the style of `.slider` you have? It seems an 'overflow' issue..

Comment: @Jamiec It could be the CSS, I'm glad to at least narrow the issue down. I thought I expanded the div enough to test is that were the issue but I will try again.

Comment: @CagatayUlubay The day display and the month does not. (Can't post images yet.) It could be height, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @MohammadAnini overflow is visible

Comment: @coozin So have you tried to set a bigger height?

Answer (score 0):

**Answered**

The height of the DIV appeared large enough to contain both lines, but after a few suggestions, I double checked the CSS and discovered the month was in fact returned to the page but just way below.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the `<br>` tag
eg.

`moment(value).format('DD\<\\b\\r\>MMMM')`

Answer (score -2):

do you mean `<br>`
you can add it class
`<br class="...">`
though I always prefer using text-decoretion:underline; or border-bottom:1px solid black;

Comment: Requests for clarifications on  question should be posted as a comment, not an answer